# responsive issue in slick slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I am facing issue in slick slider, when it reaches at `breakpoint` like `990px`.
it removes background and didn't show any type of error.
[**iconic**](http://www.viral.com.my/iconic/)

And i am using this javascript for responsiveness.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".home_carousel").slick({
        dots: false,
        autoplay: true,
        infinite: true,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
         responsive: [
            {
              breakpoint: 990,
              settings: {
              slidesToShow: 2
              }
            },
            {
              breakpoint: 668,
              settings: {
             arrows: false,
             centerMode: false,
             slidesToShow: 1
              }
            }
        ]
    });         
});
```

Comment: you are calling images in inline, try to use another class to add image. slick slider removes inline style to "_.$slider.children().children().children()
                .css({
                    'width':(100 / _.options.slidesPerRow) + '%',
                    'display': 'inline-block'
                });"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove This css on line 4692 (style.css)
After see slider in all media device

```
@media (max-width: 570px)
style.css?ver=2013-07-18:4692
.home .slider_div {
    /* display: none; */
}
```

Comment: problem occurs even at 989px, then how this will work.?

Comment: use font-size:100%; in css media query

Comment: create project on feelancer

Answer (score 1):

replace this:

```
<div class="high_post" style="background: url('http://www.viral.com.my/iconic/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/event.jpg'); ">
<div class="high_post" style="background: url('http://www.viral.com.my/iconic/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/local.jpg'); ">
```

to

```
<div class="img1 high_post">
<div class="img2 high_post">
and in css
.img1{
background: url('http://www.viral.com.my/iconic/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/event.jpg');
}
.img2{
background: url('http://www.viral.com.my/iconic/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/local.jpg');
}
```

similar to this replace all slider. hope this will works
if that too not works you can add image by

```
if ($(window).width() <= 989) {
$(".img1").css({ 'background': "http://www.viral.com.my/iconic/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/event.jpg" });
}
```

Comment: actually these are thumbnail and i am using wordpress then how can call it in css.